# how to execute a java program in a package

Tags: java

I have a directory, `E:\test\access`... 
In `E:\test` I created a file `Coffee.java` containing:

```
package test;
public class Coffee
{
    protected void service(){
        System.out.println("i am service in coffee");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
class Cafe
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Coffee c=new Coffee();
        c.service();
    }
}
```

I executed the following commands:

```
E:\test> javac Coffee.java                     
E:\test> java test.Cafe
```

and it worked. Next I went into the `E:\test\access` directory and created the following file, `Coffee1.java`:

```
package access;
import test.Coffee;
public class Coffee1 extends Coffee
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Coffee c=new Coffee();
        c.service();
        Coffee1 c1=new Coffee1();
        c1.service();
    }
}
```

I imported and extended Coffee, right? So why cant i create an object of that class?
I later commented that stuff and tried to compile and execute the program

2: I ran

```
E:\test\access> javac Coffee1.java
```

and it compiled.

If I run this:

```
E:\test\access> java access.Coffee1
```

It gives me an error saying it can't find the main method.

The same worked with Coffee.java in the test folder. Why didn't it work here?

I am unable to get how this package works and how protected stuff can work for subclasses in the other packages. Please explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Java expects your directory structure to mirror your package structure. If your `Coffee1` class is in `test\access`, it should be in package `test.access`, and you should execute `javac` and `java` from the root (`E:\` in this case), something like this:

```
E:\> javac test\access\Coffee1.java
```

Answer (score -1):

You can execute the package file [To learn about packages you should see this tutorial. precise explanation to all your questions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_packages.htm)

```
javac -d . UrJavaFilename.java
```

and to run

```
java packageName.className
```

and if You are importing the other classes then You can use:- you should define what you import and provide a classpath

```
Javac -cp e:\Yourdir; -d . UrJavaFilename.java
```